# Having trouble with memcpy

Tags: c, memcpy, c-strings

Code I'm using:

```
char** list  
char** final;
char* target;
char* replace;
int wCounter, cCounter, i, hashCounter = 0, addLetter = 0;
int copyWord, countChars, numOfWords, finalWords = 0, temp;

//stuff here

for(wCounter; wCounter < temp + numOfWords; wCounter++, finalWords++)
{
    printf("Original string: %s\n", list[wCounter+1]);
    final[finalWords] = strstr(list[wCounter+1], target);

    if(final[finalWords] != NULL)
        memcpy(final[finalWords], replace, strlen(target));

    printf("Final string: %s\n\n", final[finalWords]);
}

//stuff here
```

My program output:

```
Target string = h   Replacement string = j

Original string: hello
   Final string: jello //works!!!

Original string: happy birthday
   Final string: jappy birthday  // should be jappy birtjday

Target string = ra  Replacement string = ar

Original string: radar
   Final string: ardar   //works!!!

Original string: are you ready
   Final string: (null)  //awkward

Original string: pirate radio rating
   Final string: arte radio rating //should be piarte ardio arting

Target string = x   Replacement string = zz

Original string: exit
   Final string: zit   //should be zzit

Original string: x-ray
   Final string: z-ray  //should be zz-ray

Original string: xerox
   Final string: zerox //should be zzerox
```

My program has a target string ('h' for example)
It also has a replacement string('j' for example)

everytime it sees an 'h' it should replace it with a 'j'

happy birthday should be jappy birtjday.

Comment: Perhaps you should really provide more details. Like, for instance, why you consider both 'jappy birtjday' and 'zzerox' correct replacements.

Comment: Do you call strstr repeatedly? If yes, show us the loop you use please.

Comment: Sorry I assumed it was self-explanatory. Added instructions. I'll add in the loop as well. Thanks

Comment: You thought that the bug in your broken code that you didn't post was self-explanatory? Fascinating. Now that you have posted the code: there is nothing there to do multiple replacements in text, so it can't possibly do what you expect of it ... I hope that is self-explanatory.

Comment: I was talking about the idea of the program...

Comment: But no one asked you for the idea of the program, so your statement about it being self-explanatory is a non-sequitur. Perhaps you're responding to n.m.'s comment, in which case you haven't read it or bothered to understand it. Why do you consider both 2 replacements and 1 replacement to be correct?

Comment: You have a slew of bugs in your code. For instance, wCounter is never initialized. For more help you should post the whole thing, not just this snippet.

Comment: I posted the code originally. He asked to see the 'for' loop conditions. I also posted my output and made statements that I thought were self explanatory. I was asked to add instructions as to what was going on. You assumed that I did not post the code. Either way I'm done arguing with you. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @n.m. Both of those are one replacement per word. For some reason the OP expects this to be "self-explanatory" without discussion or code, despite there being other possibilities.

Comment: Arguing? I wasn't aware that we were doing that. Good luck here with your attitude.

Comment: I posted the variable types. Stated //some code and showed the snippet I was having trouble with. Since I did state that I had an output, you could've assumed everything was initialized. Either way, I got the answer I wanted with a clear explanation and with another way to tackle the problem. You came with the attitude. I apologized to the n.m for assuming it was self-explanatory and you had to rudely throw your two cents in. Good day.

Comment: "throw your two cents in" -- Yes, that's what we do here at SO when we try to help people with questions. "you could've assumed everything was initialized" -- it's not initialized in the code you posted -- either that's not the code you're running, or the assumption is wrong. And failure to initialize is a common problem with neophyte code posted here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, there are a several issues with your code.

First of all: strstr returns only the pointer to the FIRST occurence of the sequence to match (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) for details). So you never get the pointers to the second or third occurence. You need to rework your concept here.

Secondly: Using memcopy to replace something is only working if the replacement is of the same length as the part to be replaced. Consider following example:

```
Address:  0123456789ABCD
Original: This is a test
Target: is
Replacement foo
```

Notice that the replacement exceeds the length of the target. Now what happens in your code? `strstr` returns address 2. You pass now this pointer to `memcpy`. What you get is the following string: `Thfo is a test`

Notice that the second 'o' of 'foo' is missing. This is because you only copy as many bytes as the target string has. If you would have copied as many bytes as the replacement has, you would have ended up with a string like `Thfoois a test`. Barely better isn't it?

I'd recommend to think again about your solution concept. Maybe a better approach is to "tokenize" the string by the occurence of your target string and concatenate the elements in order to get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation. That makes complete sense.

Comment: "strstr returns only the pointer to the FIRST occurence of the sequence to match (see here for details)." -- The OP apparently only wants one replacement per word. I think there's a loop that executes per word, but it doesn't bother to initialize variables like `wCounter`, `numOfWords`, or `temp` ... whatever that is for.

Comment: "you are simply wrong" -- about what? That is one replacement per word, as I said. " instead of ranting" -- I beg your pardon? That gets a flag.

Comment: Everytime it sees the target string it replaces it with my replacement string.

Could've been hhhhappy birthday and that would be equivalent to jjjjappy birtjday. It is stated in the instructions. 

Again, thanks Junix for the different approach.

Comment: Jappy birtjday is, as I said, only one replacement per word, so I'm not the one who is wrong or needs to calm down.

Comment: @JimBalter as you know `strstr` doesn't work on a "per word" base. And there was no indication that he is splitting the string somewhere in a "per word" base. So what's your point?

Comment: " hhhhappy birthday and that would be equivalent to jjjjappy birtjday" -- obviously not, since you consider zzerox the correct replacement for xerox, not zzerozz -- this was n.m.'s point. Or rather, the point is that your examples are inconsistent so it isn't possible to know your intent without it being explicitly stated.

Comment: 'JimBalter as you know strstr doesn't work on a "per word" base' -- yes, but not relevant to what the OP *wants*, which is what I commented on. 'And there was no indication that he is splitting the string somewhere in a "per word" base' -- indeed, but not relevant. 'So what's your point?' -- I've made it clear in my previous comments; I won't discuss this further.

Comment: *sigh* When did I say I considered zerox was the correct replacement? I put that it should be zzerox. 

My examples have a target/replace string. Then they have an original/final string (which is my output).

Comment: @JimBalter Firstly: It weren't my examples, I'm also just a visitor of this question trying to give an answer as you might have noticed. Secondly: Whatever it is with the examples: Either if it's on a word base or the xerox example is wrong we don't know. I only see that the OP originally called `strstr` only once on a multi word string. Hence my answer. And also because of that I don't agree with your comment. But I already feel that this discussion with you leads to nowhere. So please forgive me if I don't answer to your comments here anymore.

Comment: @CarlosCarrillo he was aiming on the fact that I was assuming that xerox should be translated into zzerozz. Which seems to be wrong, but won't change the overall insight that you have to call `strstr` repeatedly for one string to achieve your goal.

Comment: Oh then yes, I made an error. I apologize Jim. It should be zzerozz.

Comment: @CarlosCarrillo Thanks for clearifying that. Hope you get your code now running. Just drop a line (here or in a new question) if you need more assistance.

Comment: "I don't agree with your comment" -- You still have not said what comment of mine you think is wrong. Perhaps it was "The OP apparently only wants one replacement per word" -- but I only said *apparently* -- that judgment follows from the examples, which have *no instances* of multiple replacements per word and one instance of a single replacement where two could occur, as well as the code which does not attempt more than one replacement per word. In other words, I was correct -- the OP *apparently* only intended one replacement per word. Only since my comment has the OP stated otherwise.

Comment: " But I already feel that this discussion with you leads to nowhere. "  -- And yet we can see that it led to Carlos being explicit about his intent and his erroneous example. You guys are young, immature, and inexperienced, but you'll learn and grow, I'm sure.

Comment: " the overall insight that you have to call strstr repeatedly for one string to achieve your goal" -- but that's not the key insight; the key insight is the second part of your answer, about how to do string replacement.

Comment: Odd that you find my arguing that I wasn't wrong, giving my reasons for why I think I wasn't wrong, to be offensive and somehow a slam against you. I did not say anything was your fault or that you made a lucky punch or any of your other charges.

Comment: And I go back to this: "Given his very first example (happy birthday translates to jappy birtjday) you are simply wrong." -- **That example does not show that I was wrong** -- again, I said that the OP apparently only intended one replacement per word, and that example doesn't show otherwise. If you had an argument that I was wrong, you never presented it.

Answer (score 1):

The [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) function is not for *replacing* one string with another, it will only work as intended if **both strings has the same length**, and **it will not replace more than one occurrence**. You will need something like [str_replace](http://coding.debuntu.org/c-implementing-str_replace) to do the job.